# MySQL Join Query without duplicate values

Tags: mysql

1. invoice table

```
 SELECT id, fname, gtotal, `date` FROM invoice WHERE id = 1;


| id |   fname | gtotal |                  date |
|----|---------|--------|-----------------------|
|  1 | Brandon |    860 | May, 11 2016 00:00:00 |
```

2. invoice_contents table,

```
SELECT * FROM invoice_contents WHERE invoice_id = 1;


| id | invoice_id |       item | price | quantity | discount | total |
|----|------------|------------|-------|----------|----------|-------|
|  1 |          1 |   Dextrose |    10 |       10 |        5 |    95 |
|  2 |          1 |   Nescaine |    20 |       30 |       10 |   540 |
|  3 |          1 | Anticavity |    30 |       10 |       25 |   225 |
```

3. This JOIN query

```
SELECT invoice.id, invoice.fname, invoice_contents.item,
       invoice_contents.price, invoice_contents.quantit,
       invoice_contents.discount, invoice_contents.total, 
       invoice.gtotal
  FROM invoice_contents
 INNER JOIN invoice ON invoice_contents.invoice_id=1 AND invoice.id=1;
```

gives this result.

```
 | id |   fname |       item | price | quantity | discount | total | gtotal |
 |----|---------|------------|-------|----------|----------|-------|--------|
 |  1 | Brandon |   Dextrose |    10 |       10 |        5 |    95 |    860 |
 |  1 | Brandon |   Nescaine |    20 |       30 |       10 |   540 |    860 |
 |  1 | Brandon | Anticavity |    30 |       10 |       25 |   225 |    860 |
```

I need this result.

```
| id |   fname |       item | price | quantity | discount | total | gtotal |
|----|---------|------------|-------|----------|----------|-------|--------|
|  1 | Brandon |   Dextrose |    10 |       10 |        5 |    95 |    860 |
|    |         |   Nescaine |    20 |       30 |       10 |   540 |        |
|    |         | Anticavity |    30 |       10 |       25 |   225 |        |
```

I am just a beginner in MySQL. I have been trying from this morning to get this kind of output by experimenting on different combinations please help me out.

Comment: SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b29412/13

Comment: It's odd that no relationship exists between these tables. But, putting that to one side, you're confusing data retrieval and data display - the latter being more properly addressed in application level code (e.g. a simple php loop)

Comment: Though not explicitly set in MySQL, the relationship is created by assigning the same number as the id field in the invoice table to the invoice_contents table's invoice_id field (courtesy: php's mysqli_insert_id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in SQL:

in this Query i save everytime fname in a variable is not equal and at the next row i compare it and return a empty string is it equal. and the same for gtotal.

the cross join is only to initialize the variables.

in this case it is important that the rows are order by fname to ensure that the same name is behind each other

```
SELECT
    invoice.id,
    IF(@last_fname = invoice.fname, '', (@last_fname:=invoice.fname)) as fname,
    invoice_contents.item,
    invoice_contents.price,
    invoice_contents.quantity,
    invoice_contents.discount,
    IF(@last_gtotal = invoice.gtotal, '', (@last_gtotal:=invoice.gtotal)) as gtotal
FROM invoice_contents
INNER JOIN invoice ON invoice_contents.invoice_id=1 AND invoice.id=1
CROSS JOIN ( select @last_fname := '' , @last_gtotal := '' ) AS parameter
ORDER BY invoice.fname;
```

**Sample**

```
MariaDB [bb]> SELECT
    ->     invoice.id,
    ->     IF(@last_fname = invoice.fname, '', (@last_fname:=invoice.fname)) AS fname,
    ->     invoice_contents.item,
    ->     invoice_contents.price,
    ->     invoice_contents.quantity,
    ->     invoice_contents.discount,
    ->     IF(@last_gtotal = invoice.gtotal, '', (@last_gtotal:=invoice.gtotal)) AS gtotal
    -> FROM invoice_contents
    -> INNER JOIN invoice ON invoice_contents.invoice_id=1 AND invoice.id=1
    -> CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @last_fname:='' , @last_gtotal:='' ) AS parameter
    -> ORDER BY invoice.fname;
+----+---------+------------+-------+----------+----------+--------+
| id | fname   | item       | price | quantity | discount | gtotal |
+----+---------+------------+-------+----------+----------+--------+
|  1 | Brandon | Dextrose   | 10.00 |       10 |     5.00 | 860.00 |
|  1 |         | Nescaine   | 20.00 |       30 |    10.00 |        |
|  1 |         | Anticavity | 30.00 |       10 |    25.00 |        |
+----+---------+------------+-------+----------+----------+--------+
3 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [bb]>
```

Comment: Because the original poster is a beginner, may I suggest you [edit] this answer to explain what's going on?

Comment: Thanks. Running your query in SQLFIDDLE demo shows the desired output. But in my wamp setup using both mysql cli and adminer.php (similar to phpmyadmin) I get the duplicate values

Comment: @Rex - can you please post some output

Comment: Working SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b29412/15 
Not the expected output - http://postimg.org/image/twnwnvy2p/

Comment: Ran the same query in MySQL CLI but got this output  http://postimg.org/image/twnwnvy2p. Also tried in my Linux LAMP setup got the same http://postimg.org/image/jsrm20jwh/

Comment: @Rex - I have change my answer - please try it again - sorry - Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112511/discussion-between-bernd-buffen-and-rex).

Comment: Getting the expected output. Thank you very much. Marked this as solved.

Answer (score 2):

@Rex, Your select is correct. You should make desired output using some script e.g. PHP.

Comment: That was my gut feeling too. This is ultimately intended for a PHP MySQL application.